Create a log file only when there were logs
Python version: 3.11.8
Hi everyone,
I am using the package logging to log of the execution. I am using logging.basicConfig to output the logs in a log file. I added it at the beginning of my python script. I realised a file was created when invoking logging.basicConfig. However, I do not want to create a log file if there were no data to log. Currently, I am getting empty files in my repository and I am having issues with a lot of files created in that repository. This is a part of my script to show you how I am using the logging package. How can I create the log file only when there were logs?.
def create_target_file(logs_file_path: str,
                       platform: str,
                        )-> str:

    try:
        
        data ={}

        try:
            logging.basicConfig(filename=logs_file_path,
                                filemode='a',
                                level=logging.INFO,
                                format="%(levelname)s | %(asctime)s | %(message)s", 
                                datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        except OSError as e:
            sleep(10)
            logging.basicConfig(filename=logs_file_path,
                                filemode='a',
                                level=logging.INFO,
                                format="%(levelname)s | %(asctime)s | %(message)s", 
                                datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        
          if platform == 'DRD':
              logging.info("Logging some important stuff")

     except Exception as e:
        
        logging.error(str(e))
        data['error_message'] = str(e)
        data['stack_trace'] = format_exc()
    
     finally:
        return dumps(data)

I am using a try-except block to prevent an error when creating the log file with logging.basicConfig. My goal is to create a log file only when the function logging is used. For example if platform is not equal to "DRD" and there was no errors, then the file must not be created.

Your try/except block doesn't help at all because you're calling logging.basicConfig(), which creates the log file, inside the try portion. If this is the only place you're logging anything, you could move the call to logging.basicConfig() to the except block, which would get you the behavior you want, but honestly that's a very odd configuration. I suspect there is a better solution to your problem, but I don't feel like I have enough context.

Hi @larsks thank you so much for your help. As I mentioned, I added only a part of my code, however what I am logging is some important data during the execution but sometimes if the execution went well, I do not log anything. That is why sometimes the log file is empty. My question is: if I move the basicConfig to except, all the previous logs will be included in the file or only after the basicConfig method?.

You should probably look at buffered logging with MemoryHandler. By default MemoryHandler buffers messages until either an Error message occurs or its capacity is reached. When either happens, it sends all buffered messages to another handler like a FileHandler.

Behind the scenes basicConfig() creates a FileHandler which by default immediately creates the file. FileHandler does have an argument - delay - to delay file creation until a log is written, but it is not accessible through basicConfig(). You will have to create the handler yourself.
import logging

logs_file_path = 'logfile.txt'

fhandler = logging.FileHandler(logs_file_path, mode='a', delay=True)

logging.basicConfig(handlers=[fhandler],
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    format="%(levelname)s | %(asctime)s | %(message)s",
                    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# at this point no file has been created/opened

logging.info('some log') # this line creates a file and writes to it



Tks. This is what I was looking for. I tried and worked for me.
